# Please help I have been getting this error, "Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform"

Tags: flutter, dart

It was working well but since after updating my flutter app and its packages, I am facing the error when I try to launch my app, I am using cloud firestore for my database. Here's the code:

```
    class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchPageState createState() => _SearchPageState();
}

class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
  Screen? size;
  int _selectedIndex = -1;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  List<Property> recentList =  [];
  List<Property> topList =  [];
  var citiesList = ["Utawala", "Vihiga", "Voi", "Wajir", "Webuye", "Wote", "Wundanyi", "Yala"];
  Image? image1;
  String? docRef;
  String? isLoggedIn;
  DocumentSnapshot? docsSnap;

  void getUserDetails() async{
    isLoggedIn= await LocalStorage.sharedInstance.loadAuthStatus(Constants.isLoggedIn);
    docRef= await LocalStorage.sharedInstance.loadUserRef(Constants.userRef);
    print('docRef :'+ docRef!);
    if(docRef != "NULL"){
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('/User/'+docRef!).get().then((DocumentSnapshot docs) {
        print("Doc found");
        setState(() {
          docsSnap = docs;
        });
      });
    }else{
      setState((){docsSnap=null;});
      print("Doc Not Exist");
    }
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    setState((){docsSnap=null;});
    getUserDetails();

    image1 = Image.asset("assets/drawer_design.png", gaplessPlayback: true);

    topList
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Omkar Lotus", propertyLocation:"Nairobi ", image:"feature_1.jpg", propertyPrice:"26000", propertyDesc: '', id: ''))
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Sandesh Heights", propertyLocation:"Mombasa ", image:"feature_2.jpg", propertyPrice:"11500", propertyDesc: '', id: ''))
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Sangath Heights", propertyLocation:"Kilifi ", image:"feature_3.jpg", propertyPrice:"19000", propertyDesc: '', id: ''))
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Adani HighRise", propertyLocation:"Kisumu ", image:"hall_1.jpg", propertyPrice:"225000", propertyDesc: '', id: ''))
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"N.G Tower", propertyLocation:"Eldoret ", image:"hall_2.jpeg", propertyPrice:"75000", propertyDesc: '', id: ''));

    recentList
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Vishwas CityRise", propertyLocation:"Nairobi ", image:"hall_1.jpg", propertyPrice:"17500", propertyDesc: '', id: ''))
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Gift City", propertyLocation:"Mombasa ", image:"hall_2.jpeg", propertyPrice:"13500000", propertyDesc: '', id: ''))
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Velone City", propertyLocation:"Kilifi ", image:"feature_1.jpg", propertyPrice:"11500000", propertyDesc: '', id: ''))
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"PabelBay", propertyLocation:"Kisumu ", image:"hall_1.jpg", propertyPrice:"33000000", propertyDesc: '', id: ''))
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Sapath Hexa Tower", propertyLocation:"Eldoret", image:"feature_3.jpg", propertyPrice:"156000", propertyDesc: '', id: ''));
  }

  // void addTopList(){
  //   final startAtTimestamp = Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(DateTime.parse('2019-03-13 16:49:42.044').millisecondsSinceEpoch);
  // }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    precacheImage(image1!.image, context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarWhiteForeground(true);
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setNavigationBarWhiteForeground(true);
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.blue[700]!.withOpacity(0.9));
    size = Screen(MediaQuery.of(context).size);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: AnnotatedRegion(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
            statusBarColor: backgroundColor,
            statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
            statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
            systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
            systemNavigationBarColor: backgroundColor),
        child: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                upperPart()
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: docsSnap != null ? drawer(image1,context,docsSnap!['profileImage'].data()['profileImage'],docsSnap!['firstName'].data()['firstName']+" "+docsSnap!['lastName'].data()['lastName'],docsSnap!['email'].data()['email'],"true",'/User/'+docRef!)
          : drawer(image1,context,'assets/icons/avatar.png','Login / Register ','','false',null),
    );
  }
```

And here's the drawer widget

```
    Widget drawer(img,context,_imageUrl,_name,_email,logStatus,docRef){
  String logStatus = LocalStorage.sharedInstance.loadAuthStatus(Constants.isLoggedIn).toString();
  Screen size = Screen(MediaQuery.of(context).size);
  return Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      children: <Widget>[
        DrawerHeader(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: size.hp(100),
              ),
              Positioned(
                right: 5,
                top: 0,
                child: logStatus == "true" && _imageUrl!=null ? userProfile(_imageUrl,true) : userProfile(_imageUrl,false),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 5,
                bottom: 27,
                child: Text(
                  _name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: 25,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 5,
                bottom: 10,
                child: Text(
                  _email,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                    fontSize: 17,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent),
            // image: DecorationImage(
            //   image: img.image,
            //   fit: BoxFit.fill,
            // ),
            color: colorCurve,
          ),
        ),

        // Search Property
        ListTile(
          title: Text(
            "Search Property",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.searchLocation,
                size: 20,
                color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
              );
            },
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => CustomSearchPage()));
            // _uri
          },
        ),

        // Post Ad
        ListTile(
          title: Text(
            "Post Free House Ad",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.home,
                size: 20,
                color: Colors.blue[700],
              );
            },
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            if(logStatus == "false"){
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Login / Signup is required');
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => FirstScreen()));
            }else{
              Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>AddHouse(docRef)));
            }
            // _uri
          },
        ),

        // My Favrourites
        ListTile(
          title: Text(
            "My Favrouites",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.solidHeart,
                size: 20,
                color: Colors.red,
              );
            },
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            if(logStatus == "false"){
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Login / Signup is required');
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => FirstScreen()));
            }else{
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Redirected to Fovroites Page');
            }
            // _uri
          },
        ),

        // Pay Rents
        ListTile(
          title: Text(
            'Pay Your Rents',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.wallet,
                size: 20,
                color: Colors.green,
              );
            },
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            if(logStatus == "false"){
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Login / Signup is required');
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => FirstScreen()));
            }else{
              Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Users()));
              // _uri
            }
          },
        ),

        // Pay Rents
        ListTile(
          title: Text(
            'Contact Users',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.users,
                size: 20,
                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
              );
            },
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            if(logStatus == "false"){
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Login / Signup is required');
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => FirstScreen()));
            }else{
              Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Users()));
              // _uri
            }
          },
        ),
        new Divider(color: Colors.black26),
        // Profile
        if(logStatus == "true")
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              'Manage Profile',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ),
            leading: Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Icon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.userAlt,
                  size: 20,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                );
              },
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ProfilePage(docRef,false)));
              // _uri
            },
          ),

        // Item About Developer
        ListTile(
          title: Text(
            'About Developers',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.code,
                size: 20,
                color: Colors.grey,
              );
            },
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=> AboutDevelopers()));
            // _uri
          },
        ),

        // Item Logout
        ListTile(
          title: Text(
            logStatus == "true" ? 'Log-Out' : 'Log-In',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Icon(
                logStatus =="true" ?FontAwesomeIcons.signOutAlt:FontAwesomeIcons.signInAlt,
                size: 20,
                color: Colors.grey,
              );
            },
          ),
          onTap: logStatus == "true"
              ? () async{
            print("Logout Pressed");
            try {
              await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
              LocalStorage.sharedInstance.setAuthStatus(key:Constants.isLoggedIn,value: "false");
              LocalStorage.sharedInstance.setUserRef(key:Constants.userRef,value: "NULL");
            } catch (e) {
              print(e);
            }
            LocalStorage.sharedInstance.setUserRef(key: Constants.userRef,value: null);
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(_) =>  SplashScreen()));
          }
              : () {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage()));
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget userProfile(_imagePath,val){
  return Container(
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(43)),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35)),
          child: val
              ? Image.network(
            _imagePath,
            height: 70,
            width: 70,
          )
              : Image.asset(
            'assets/icons/avatar.png',
            height: 70,
            width: 70,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I have been on this for days now not sure how to go about it. I have tried removing my initial drawer argument in the Searchpage by just calling the drawer(), but same error. And this goes for the vice versa removing the drawer widget and maintaining the code in the searchpage

Comment: Please share the full stack trace error

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is being caused by this:

```
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('/User/'+docRef!).get().then((DocumentSnapshot docs) {
```

You are asking Firebase to get you a document, from a specific path, but this document does NOT exist. Share a picture from your Firebase, so we can see how your collection looks like and what user is causing you an error, it most likely is being caused by a spelling mistake.

Start by changing your code to this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('User').doc(docRef!).get().then((DocumentSnapshot docs) {
       if(docs.exists){ //To check if the document exists before performing operations on it
        print("Doc found");
        setState(() {
          docsSnap = docs;
        });
      });
     }
    }else{
      setState((){docsSnap=null;});
      print("Doc Not Exist");
    }
```

Also, why are you doing this?

```
docsSnap!['profileImage'].data()['profileImage'],docsSnap!['firstName'].data()['firstName']..
```

Change it to:

```
docsSnap!.data()['profileImage'],docsSnap!.data()['firstName']+
```

Comment: here's the link to the screenshot https://imgur.com/RzdSM77.

Comment: And after changing my code to your recommended code I still get the same error

Comment: have you seen it @Huthaifa

Comment: I found it I did pluralize docsSnap and docs

Comment: apparently that wasnt the solution everytime i do a hot restart i keep getting the same error

Comment: Do the same for the rest in this line `docsSnap!.get('firstName')`